# Multiple results + Array displays

Tags: php

this query matches with two fields in the database. How can i grab both of the names from the DB?

```
        $product_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `templates` WHERE `cat_id` = '$catid'") or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
        $product_array = mysql_fetch_array($product_q);
        $product_name = $product_array['name']; //got the first results 'name'
        $product_name2 = $product_name[1]; // attempted to get the 2nd 'name'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must loop through the results. Like so:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($product_q) )
{
    $product_name = $row['name'];
    echo $product_name;
}
```

Comment: I thought i could just grab the array variable and do $name[0] and $name[1]?

Comment: Nope, you can however loop through your result and build an array yourself so you can access the data like $product_array[0]['name'] or $product_array[1]['name'] for the second product. That also makes it possible to use a foreach loop instead of a while. But this is the starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop, or do this

```
 $product_q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `templates` WHERE `cat_id` = '$catid'") or die("<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
    $product_array = mysql_fetch_array($product_q); // First prod
    $product_name = $product_array['name'];

    $product_array = mysql_fetch_array($product_q); // Second prod
    $product_name2 = $product_array['name'];
```

The loop:

```
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($product_q) )
{
    $productname= $r['name'];
}
```

For each row in your result you need to do 1 mysql_fetch_array. When there is no row left it will return null.

If you want all rows in 1 array you can do this

```
$products = array();
while($r= mysql_fetch_array($product_q) )
{
    $products[] = $r;
}

// Echo first product
echo $products[0]['name'];

// Echo second product
echo $products[1]['name'];

... and so on
```

Comment: I like your first method. If i wanted to make more names would i just simply add
    $product_array = mysql_fetch_array($product_q); // Second prod
    $product_name3 = $product_array['name'];
    $product_array = mysql_fetch_array($product_q); // Second prod
    $product_name4 = $product_array['name'];

etc..

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to get the names from the two tables why not just put them in the columns to be selected?

```
$query = "SELECT table1.name as name1, table2.name as name FROM table1, table2";
```

That way you can get it the way you want to:

```
$product_array = mysql_fetch_array($query);
echo $product_array['name1'];
echo $product_array['name2'];
```